# How can I create a custom ListView with EditText in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, mobile

I'm designing a simple app in Android Studio where the user can add items to a listview. Every cell in the listview has an edittext where the user inputs a number. When a button is clicked, the app needs to get all the numbers in the edittext's to do some math with.

I was able to get up to adding items in the listview but I'm not able to get the values from the edittext's. In iOS it's simple. I can just loop through every cell position and reference that instance of the cell to get edittext values.

I've searched all over Google, but there is nothing using Kotlin. If anyone can help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With RecyclerView or the obsolete ListView, it's up to you to track the data for each row. You create a data class that has properties for all the types of information might appear on a row, and you update the item for that row when the user changes it (like checking a check box or entering text in an edit text). You should use RecyclerView instead of ListView, and there are many tutorials online for how to do it.

Comment: It's simple in android as well. First thing use recyclerview not list view as it's old fashioned. Use list of some class and it should have a field which will hold data for that row's edittext whenever it's value changes and you can add text change listener for that purpose and on click of button just loop through that list and take the field value.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use recycler view instead of list view for better performance.

Second, you'll have to pass a list to the recycler view adapter. Please follow the below steps to get the value of every text field.

1. Create a UI data class which will be populated with the actual data
   in either use case or viewModel.
2. Whenever the user type's anything, override onTextChanged() and
   modify the value in the UI model class and not the actual data class that you get from the API or DB.
3. Now you have the desired data stored in the UI data class.

Now you can do whatever you want with your data.